# JFreeChart and PDFbox

Tags: java, png, pdfbox, jfreechart

How to add `JFreeChart` as png/jpeg in PDFBox? I tried using PDXObject image, but its not available in version 1.8.11 which is currently used in the project. Kindly help me with the sample code and version.

Answer (score 1):

In 1.8.* the classes to be used are `PDJpeg` for jpg and `PDPixelMap` for png. They are instanciated with `new`. But you should really update, not just to 1.8.16, but migrate to 2.0.26.

Comment: Thanks ,could you please share a sample code how to use them in jfreechart?

Comment: No, I don't know anything about JFreechart. I can tell you how to use the two classes but that's already been answered, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50246536/

Comment: [tag:jfreechart] provides [`org.jfree.chart.ChartUtils`](https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartUtils.html), which has methods to save or stream a chart image in any of several formats.